# Access images for my project when it is embedded in another project

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding, prism

I have the following situation:

- ProjectA needs to show an image on a `UserControl`.
  It has the image in its project (can be a Resource or whatever).
- But ProjectA is just a dll.  It is used by ProjectB (via Prism).

So doing this in ProjectA works for **design time** (if the MyImage.png file is set to "Resource" compile action):

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/ProjectA;component/MyImage.png"></Image>
```

But at run time, all that is copied to ProjectB is the dll (and that is all I want copied.  So MyImage.png is present in the running folder... and it does not show an image.

I thought that Making it Resource would embed it but it does not seem to work.

I also tried to use a Resources.resx and that does not seem to work at all (or I can't find the way to bind the image in xaml).

**How can I put the image inside my dll and then reference it from there (or some other non-file system dependent way to get the image)?**

Comment: Of course it won't work. Image is embedded as a bytestream in resources of ProjectA. If you don't include ProjectA.dll in output folder then pack uri won't resolve. Either put the image in ProjectB or create a dll which will hold your images and always get copied to output folder.

Answer (score 1):

I put together a WPF application with 2 projects to see if I could recreate the problem. Unforunately, it all just worked.  I used the same pack uri format from your post and I was able to display the picture directly in an image control from both projects and also have the usercontrol from "Project A" show the image when put in the window on Project B.  NB: I set the picture to have a build action of resource and set it to "do not copy".

Given that it works in a simple scenario my next thought is whether the problem has anything to do with the fact that you are using PRISM.  I will have a look and see what I can find.